# `isin` fails to detect a row that is in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've been struggling with an error for days, and after many conversations with ChatGPT, finally got it boiled down to this one minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create two data frames with duplicate values
goal_df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1], 'sentence_id': [2]})
source_df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1, 1], 'sentence_id': [2, 2]})

# The first assertion passes
assert (goal_df[['user_id', 'sentence_id']].iloc[0] == source_df[['user_id', 'sentence_id']].iloc[0]).all()

# The second assertion fails
assert goal_df[['user_id', 'sentence_id']].iloc[0].isin(source_df[['user_id', 'sentence_id']]).all()
```

*Why does the second assertion fail?*

When I print out intermediate values, it looks like even if I replaced the `all` with `any`, it would still fail. That is, the `isin` is saying that the `user_id` and `sentence_id` aren't in the `source_df` at all, despite the line just beforehand proving that they are.

I also thought that maybe it was because there was an indexing issue where the example didn't match the index, as it's required to by [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), however, even if you make `source_df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1], 'sentence_id': [2]})`, the same behavior occurs (first assert passes, second fails.)

What's going on here?

Comment: In second assertion type of goal_df = series (because of the use of iloc) whereas type of source_df = dataframe. Thus assertion = False. If you try with the two dataframes it works. ```goal_df.isin(source_df)```

Answer (score 2):

As Laurent pointed out, `isin()` is not the right tool here. Instead, you can extend the approach from your first assertion to the full `source_df` dataframe by using NumPy [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Assuming `goal_df` has just one row and `source_df` has any number of rows, while both dataframes have the same number of columns, the following assertion checks that the row from `goal_df` is present as a row somewhere in `source_df`.

```py
assert (goal_df.values == source_df.values).all(axis=1).any()
```

This works because the `values` attribute gives the values from within the dataframes as NumPy arrays. When these arrays are compared with `==`, the first array is broadcast to match the dimensions of the second one, meaning its one row is repeated as many times as is the number of rows in the second dataframe. Then for each position the values from both arrays are compared, resulting in a Boolean array with the same shape as the second dataframe.

With `all(axis=1)` we collapse each row of this array to a single Boolean value, indicating if all the values in that row are `True`, i.e. if the corresponding row of the second dataframe completely matches the first dataframe. Finally, `any()` lets the assertion pass if such a match was found for any of the rows.

Comment: Came back to alter my answer to this, this should be the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the second assertion, and check the different parts :

```py
type(goal_df[['user_id', 'sentence_id']].iloc[0])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

type(source_df[['user_id', 'sentence_id']])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Then in second expression you are trying to check if Series elements **are in** a dataframe.

Problem is that `isin` Series method is not designed for that.

Like documentation exposed `isin` method for series can only take `a set or list-like` as values argument :

> values : set or list-like

> The sequence of values to test.

> Passing in a single string will raise a TypeError. Instead, turn a single string
> into a list of one element.

So Assertion is considered as False, and an Assertion exception is raised

**Proposed script**

```py
# Proposed second Assertion
src = source_df[['user_id', 'sentence_id']].to_numpy().flatten() # Dataframe to numpy list array

assert goal_df[['user_id', 'sentence_id']].iloc[0].isin(src).all()
```

**Checking row by row**

I just read your comment, try this (Arne new one is excellent) :

```py
assert (goal_df.isin(source_df).sum(axis=1) == len(source_df.columns)).all()
```

Comment: The @Arne approach is not logically equivalent since it does not check for the whole row. If the second array was `{'user_id': [1, 1], 'sentence_id': [1, 1]}` then it still produces **True**.

Comment: @user19077881 thanks for pointing that out. I have deleted the comment.

Comment: The proposed second assertion passes even if `source_df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [2, 2], 'sentence_id': [1, 1]})`, which is not what I want. My goal is to grab out rows from the `source_df` that match rows in the `goal_df` for these two particular columns.

Answer (score 0):

As Laurent above explained; the `isin()` method is applied to a `Series` (`iloc[int]` returns a `Series`), and checks for each value in that series if it is in the itterable you provide.

If I understand your question right, you are trying to check if a row from one DF exists in another DF, correct? One way of solving that is to do a merge and count the length of the result:

```
assert len(pd.merge(goal_df, source_df, how='inner')) > 0
```